# Export into excel file or .csv file from datatable of website in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, web-applications, datatable

In my website there is an admin section where I can see the total database tables by choosing database name from dropdown list. Now i want to export the database value to excel file(.xlsx)/ .csv file which will stored into anywhere in my computer i want to save. Previously I used .dll file to export data which was running perfectly in my localhost. But that time it showed error that I don't have any permission to use .dll file in my site. My site is hosted in Hostgaror. My database's column number can be vary to different databases.

So can anybody please tell me how to export datatable into excel file or .csv in my website's page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library.

Dump your datatable to excel using LoadFromTable() function.

Comment: i cannot use library function in my website because of some security issue in my hosting server. Is there any other way to do same ?